# How do I implement IP-based export restrictions for my data stored on Amazon S3?

Tags: ip, amazon-s3, blacklist

A little background: Corporate wants to make our downloads unavailable to U.S. export-restricted countries like North Korea, Iran, Syria, etc. Restriction by IP-block is considered good enough. (Yes, I know better, but it's a CYA matter for the suits)

Is there a way to implement IP-based ACLs on S3 without having to put a server of my own in the path?

Relatedly, this would seem to be a common requirement - is there a standard blacklist of said IP blocks I can incorporate?

Comment: Gotta love corporate legal departments.

Answer (score 3):

One way to go about it would be to [write a bucket policy](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/writebucketpolicy.html) to block the IP address ranges you're interested in. (IP address lists by country can be found all over the Internet; ask Google.)

Another way is to make the entire bucket private, and [generate pre-signed URLs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) for users after they agree to some click-through agreement that they won't export to $COUNTRY, etc. This is probably reasonable enough (many, many organizations do this) and the URLs are time-limited so they can't be easily shared.

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that S3 supported IP ACL entries?!? Very cool.